# awk check if the value of a specific field exist in an array or a file

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Please i have this code:

```
awk -F' *\\| *' 'FNR==NR {a[$1];next} $2==2 && $4==3 && $5 in a &&  ($3==11 || $8 in ..)'  file1.conf file2
```

And i want to add another condition which verifies that the field $8 exist in an array of value [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ..] ?

I use already a file to check if the value of $5 exist in the file but i don't know how can I add another array to check existence of the value of filed $8 in the array or file

here is the list.txt file:

```
1 #error code

2 #submit code

3 #delivery code

.

.
```

thank you

Comment: Is this new array an awk array or a BASH array?

Comment: I can put the values in a file but I have to put across from each one a comment like this: 

1 #the error code
2 # submit code
.
.

And I can also put the values in code

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by `array of value[1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ..] `

Comment: generally I must check if the filed $8 exist in a list

Comment: What list ? What is filed $8 ?

Comment: There is no direct function to check if a value is there in an array or not. You have to scan it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your list data is in a file called `list.txt` you can then modify your `awk` command to:

```
awk -F' *\\| *' -v lf='list.txt' 'BEGIN {
       while (getline p < lf) {
          sub(/[ #].*$/, "", p);
          d[p];
       }
       close(lf)
    }
    FNR==NR {
       a[$1];next
    }
    $2==2 && $4==3 && $5 in a &&  ($3=11 || $8 in d)'  file1.conf file2
```

Comment: I can't test it without seeing data from all of the 3 input files and your expected output. But this new code has been tested and it  definitely works.

Comment: no no the probleme was in code "$3==11" it works now! thak you but if i want to add a comment in list.txt ? before each line

Comment: It worked for me. Can you post your `list.txt` in your question?

Comment: because the comment should be in front of value example: 2 #error code

Comment: I added the list.txt in the question on top

Comment: ah because in my list.txt the values and comments are separated with a tabulation. now it works thank you very match anubhava!